# Invertible elements in the ring completion of a semiring.

Tags: linear-algebra, semiring

Let $R$ be a commutative semiring with unit.

Assume that addition is cancellative so that $R$ is included in its ring completion.

Fix ${a, b \in R}$.
A simple calculation shows that ${a - b}$ is invertible in the ring completion of $R$ if and only if there are ${x, y \in R}$ such that ${a x + b y = 1 + a y + b x}$.

I am looking for (nontrivial, needless to say) general sufficient conditions on $R$ guaranteeing that, for ${a, b, x, y}$ as above,
${a \leq b}$ or ${b\leq a}$ in $R$.

Do you know some?

Comment: How do you define $\leq$ in $R$?

Comment: ${a \leq b}$ if and only if there is a $d$ such that ${a + d = b}$.

Comment: But if $R$ is already a ring, this relation is the universal relation.

Comment: Yes. I don't mind about rings or distributive lattices. I am thinking of quotients of ${k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]}$ where $k$ is some `good' semiring $k$ such as ${\mathbb{N}}$ or the positive rationals or positive reals.